# SQL: Joining tables with WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join two tables that share the same individual ID (`key`). The first table (`a`) is a 'wide' table with many variables including `key` and `age`, and the second table (`b`) is a 'long' table, including only the variables `key`, `diagnosis_number`, and `diagnosis`, where each individual can have multiple values of `diagnosis`.

I want to select columns `key`, `age`, and the primary diagnosis for individuals where:

- `diagnosis` = "a", "b", or "c" when `diagnosis_number` = 1 [the 'primary diagnosis']
- AND `diagnosis` = "y" for any of `diagnosis_number` = 2:20

I've tried:

```
SELECT main.key, main.age, diag.diagnosis
FROM a as main

INNER JOIN
    
(

   SELECT prim.key, prim.diagnosis
   FROM

   (SELECT DISTICT key, diagnosis
    FROM b
    WHERE diagnosis IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
    AND diagnosis_number = 1) as prim

   INNER JOIN

   (SELECT DISTICT key, diagnosis
    FROM b
    WHERE diagnosis = 'y'
    AND diagnosis_number BETWEEN 2 AND 20) as sec

   ON prim.key = sec.key) as diag

ON main.key = diag.key
```

Comment: `WHERE diagnosis IN ("a", "b", "c)` <<-- you should use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Think this could be solved without subqueries/SELECTs inside of joins:</s>

### SQL Server

```
SELECT a.key, a.age, b.diagnosis
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON b.key = a.key
WHERE b.diagnosis IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
    AND b.diagnosis_code = 1
    AND a.key IN (SELECT b1.key 
                  FROM b AS b1
                  WHERE b1.diagnosis = 'y'
                      AND b1.diagnosis_code BETWEEN 2 AND 20)
```

Comment: This is ANSI SQL, and expected to work with _any_ dbms.

Comment: Thank you. Individuals in `a` have multiple diagnoses, which are listed in `b`. I am trying to get unique individuals that have a diagnosis 'a', 'b', or 'c' in position 1 (the primary diagnosis), AND the diagnosis 'y' in position 2:20. I think this query will return a table of diagnoses that meet either of these conditions, with multiple rows per individual.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying--I have edited my query, does this look like it might be more accurate for your desired results?

Comment: I think it does!! I am just going to run some checks and will then accept your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)